# Apply background color of a div using ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic3, ionic4

How to change background color of the below `div` using ionic4

```
<div class="changeColor">hello world</div>
```

what i tried is below

```
.changeColor{
    //width:100%;//notworking
    //background-color: white; //not working


       --background:white !important;
}
```

> Only inline style is working ?. I think i am facing this because of **shadow dom**

Any help ??

Comment: `.changeColor { --ion-background-color: #FFFFFF; }`

Comment: I guess your problem should be solved by above code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--ion-background-color` or `--ion-background-color-rgb` property to change background color in Ionic-4 beta.

```
.changeColor {
  /* background color with hex format */
  --ion-background-color: #ffffff;
  /* background color with rgb format */
  --ion-background-color-rgb: 255,255,255;
}
```

And I suggest you review [the official article](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced/) about Theming in Ionic-4.

Answer (score -1):

For your case you don't need to update background by using css4 variable, you can use the basic css.

```
.changeColor {
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, As you can see in my question i have clearly mentioned this css which you have applied is not working in ionic4

Comment: hmmm, do you add custom div and want to set background for it, or you want to change background to web component ?

For your custom div my last answer should be work, but for web component ex:
<checkbox class="custom-class"></checkbox>

// in css file

use name of component 

checkbox {
--background:white
}

Comment: Hi, could you post more pieces of the code? the component's declaration? I just tried this and it works

Comment: use --ion-background-color instead of --background

Answer (score -1):

use can use the basic css :

```
.changeColor{background-color:white;}
```

Hope It helps :)